# How to store a session variable for someone with disabled cookies in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, session-cookies

I'm currently using an active records session store in rails.

I use it to store a value which I pass to the view page of a model once a successful create event has happened. I only want the value to trigger on the first visit to the view page and never again.

I've noticed on browsers with cookie disabled that this value isn't coming through. I thought using active record as the store would solve this but it didn't.

Is there a way to pass a value to a page, either using sessions or otherwise (I can't have any querystrings since users will be bookmarking the page and it saves the value if they do).

Comment: ain't it a way to using a database field to record it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ActiveRecord session store just means that session data is stored in a DB instead of the cookie itself. A cookie is still needed to identify the client on subsequent requests. An alternative option to identify the client would be via a session id that is passed as a uri parameter. However, this would mean that the session id is disclosed and everyone that knows it, can hijack the session. In addition, this is not built into rails.

Comment: Still a cookie hmm - thanks. I guess I could create a database field saying "first view complete" and only set it to true after first view, then I wouldn't need cookies i dont think.

Comment: My point is that you will have difficulties re-identifying the specific user/session unless he transmits some kind of id, which is done via cookies in rails.

Comment: Thanks - I probably need this more for identifying the first time a record is accessed rather than identifying the user as they are all anonymous either way. I was just using sessions as a way to avoid query strings and as a very short term params store.